# Div that show/hide only one div with .show/.hide but not the other on click JS /JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I work on a display panel that display info. I have a panel with some tab [image: like this]

I succeed to remove a class to show the button active or not with Jquery and JS but I didn't success to display the div that match with the current tab selected. the first tab is hide/show if I click on it or in other tab but the other aren't display when I click on them so I don't understand why this works with only one of my tab.

here is my code:
the tab that work

```
function activeButton_1088()
{
    $('#button-1089').removeClass('x-active x-tab-active x-tab-default-active x-top-active x-tab-top-active x-tab-default-top-active').show(500);
    $('#button-1090').removeClass('x-active x-tab-active x-tab-default-active x-top-active x-tab-top-active x-tab-default-top-active').show(500);
    $('#button-1091').removeClass('x-active x-tab-active x-tab-default-active x-top-active x-tab-top-active x-tab-default-top-active').show(500);
    $('#button-1092').removeClass('x-active x-tab-active x-tab-default-active x-top-active x-tab-top-active x-tab-default-top-active').show(500);
    $('#button-1093').removeClass('x-active x-tab-active x-tab-default-active x-top-active x-tab-top-active x-tab-default-top-active').show(500);
    $('#button-1094').removeClass('x-active x-tab-active x-tab-default-active x-top-active x-tab-top-active x-tab-default-top-active').show(500);
    $('#button-1095').removeClass('x-active x-tab-active x-tab-default-active x-top-active x-tab-top-active x-tab-default-top-active').show(500);

    if ($('#button-1088').hasClass('x-active x-tab-active x-tab-default-active x-top-active x-tab-top-active x-tab-default-top-activeanier'))
    {
        alert("already on this tab !");
    }
    else
    {
        $('#button-1088').addClass('x-active x-tab-active x-tab-default-active x-top-active x-tab-top-active x-tab-default-top-active').show(500);
    }

    $('#headercontainer-1023').hide(500);
    $('#gridBaseProducts-body').hide(500);
    $('#header-user').show(1000);
    $('#gridUserData-body').show(1000);
}
```

and the code that doesn't work:

```
function activeButton_1089()
{
    $('#button-1088').removeClass('x-active x-tab-active x-tab-default-active x-top-active x-tab-top-active x-tab-default-top-active').show(500);
    $('#button-1090').removeClass('x-active x-tab-active x-tab-default-active x-top-active x-tab-top-active x-tab-default-top-active').show(500);
    $('#button-1091').removeClass('x-active x-tab-active x-tab-default-active x-top-active x-tab-top-active x-tab-default-top-active').show(500);
    $('#button-1092').removeClass('x-active x-tab-active x-tab-default-active x-top-active x-tab-top-active x-tab-default-top-active').show(500);
    $('#button-1093').removeClass('x-active x-tab-active x-tab-default-active x-top-active x-tab-top-active x-tab-default-top-active').show(500);
    $('#button-1094').removeClass('x-active x-tab-active x-tab-default-active x-top-active x-tab-top-active x-tab-default-top-active').show(500);
    $('#button-1095').removeClass('x-active x-tab-active x-tab-default-active x-top-active x-tab-top-active x-tab-default-top-active').show(500);

    if ($('#button-1089').hasClass('x-active x-tab-active x-tab-default-active x-top-active x-tab-top-active x-tab-default-top-activeanier'))
    {
        alert("Vous êtes déjà sur cette onglet !");
    }
    else
    {
        $('#button-1089').addClass('x-active x-tab-active x-tab-default-active x-top-active x-tab-top-active x-tab-default-top-active').show(500);
    }


    $('#header-user').hide(500);
    $('#gridUserData-body').hide(500);
    $('#headercontainer-1023').show(500);
    $('#gridBaseProducts-body').show(500);       
}
```

here is the DIV that I would like to show that doesn't work :

```
    <div id ="gridBaseProducts-body" class="x- 
      panel-body x-grid-body x-panel-body- 
      default x-panel-body-default x-layout- 
      fit">
         <div class="x-grid-view x-fit-item x-grid-view-default x-unselectable" id="gridview-1025" tabindex="-1" style="overflow: auto;"></div>
         <table class="x-grid-table x-grid- table-resizer" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:936px;height:1px;"> 
    <?php $compteurfood=1; ?>
           <tbody>
       <?php              
           foreach($obj_store_BP->fetchAll() as $obj_BP)
           { ?>
           <tr class="x-grid-header-row">
             <th class="x-grid-col-resizer- rownumberer-1011" style="width: 23px; height: 0px;"><?php echo $compteurfood; ?> </th>
             <th class="x-grid-col-resizer-email" style="width: 70px; height: 0px;"><?php echo "{$obj_BP->food_baseproduct}"; ?></th>
              <th class="x-grid-col-resizer-gridcolumn-1012" style="width: 95px; height: 0px;"> <?php echo "{$obj_BP->food_basec02}"; ?></th> 
   <?php $compteurfood++; ?>
              </tr>
      <?php } ?>
           </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: You should really look in to the DRY principle. You can reduce that code (and the number of repeated functions) massively, if you organise the logic properly.

Comment: So if you click on the first tab, it works, and at second click it doesn't work?

Comment: To complement @RoryMcCrossan 's comment. Instead of using `#button-1088`, why not use `.data()` method and create a generic function that requires a button `data-id` and `delay`?

Comment: because you have `x-tab-default-top-activeanier` in hasClass condition rather than `x-tab-default-top-active` in the code which doesn't work

Comment: you can toggle the class using the same string to avoid the typing error

Comment: The #button-1088 is the id of one of my button you say that there is something that could allow me to do like a loop with less code the same thing ? interested. And Yes @MártonRóbert when I click on the first tab the div is show and when I click on another tab the div is hide but the other div ( div of the other tab) doesn't show.

Comment: @TerryWei yeah I changed it but this if statement is for the css that change the appearance of the button (grey like disabled or white when active) and this part works

Comment: add full html code...!